# How to setup GitHub server locally

Tags: git, github

I installed git in my Windows machine and did some changes and was able to push to my git repository that is hosted by github.com. My concern is that I don't want to push my changes to a github.com repo. I want to create my own repo so that I will be able to push changes hosted by my server. Please suggest me how to do that in windows machine.

Comment: There's no such thing as a GitHub server. You can clone repos using git itself. GitHub is a *lot* more than Git though, it's the project hosting, issue tracking etc. If you want a similar integrated UI try a product like Gitlab or Googs

Comment: Try Gerrit instead of Github

Comment: BTW you already have a repo - your local one. Why do you want to push to another? If it's for backup purposes, you could even create a git repo on a file share. You could start git daemon from the command line or TortoiseGit itself if you have many users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. GitHub is proprietary software which you cannot download and install on your own Windows servers.

However, there is [GitHub enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home).

An alternative would be [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) or gitolite if you don't need a fancy web interface.

Comment: Ok so after using GitHub enterprise or Gitlab i will be able to push my changes to my server like git remote add origin git@git.sami.int.abc.com:Research.git

Comment: @SUDARSHAN what are you trying to do? If you only want a repo, you can use git itself. GitHub is more than a hosted git

Comment: Yeah, but both don't run on windows.